# Android: ViewPager using getChildStaticTransformation with WebView Fragments behaving strangely

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have extended a version of [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/) and added rotation transition animations (using [android.graphics.Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html)) to the viewpager.

The important transformation code applied in getChildStaticTransformation is as follows:

```
@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    if (child.getHeight() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int childPosition = child.getTop() / child.getHeight();
    final boolean isFirstOrLast = childPosition == 0 || (childPosition == getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
    if (childPosition < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(isFirstOrLast && childOffsetVals[childPosition] == -1){
        childOffsetVals[childPosition] = 0;
    }
    int offFactor = 2;
    float dx = getWidth() / offFactor;
    int dy = getHeight() / offFactor;

    if (childOffsetVals[childPosition] > 0) {
        float rotateX = (ROTATION_FACTOR * childOffsetVals[childPosition]);
        float translateY = (TRANSLATION_FACTOR * childOffsetVals[childPosition]);
        t.getMatrix().reset();
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.rotateX(rotateX);
        mCamera.translate(0, translateY, 0);
        mCamera.getMatrix(t.getMatrix());
        mCamera.restore();
        t.getMatrix().preTranslate(-dx, -(dy));
        t.getMatrix().postTranslate(dx, (dy));
    } else if (childOffsetVals[childPosition] < 0 && childOffsetVals[childPosition] > -1) {
        float rotateX = -(ROTATION_FACTOR * childOffsetVals[childPosition]);
        float translateY = -(TRANSLATION_FACTOR * childOffsetVals[childPosition]);
        t.getMatrix().reset();
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.rotateX(rotateX);
        mCamera.translate(0, translateY, 0);
        mCamera.getMatrix(t.getMatrix());
        mCamera.restore();
        t.getMatrix().preTranslate(-dx, -(dy * offFactor));
        t.getMatrix().postTranslate(dx, (dy * offFactor));
    } 
    else {
        t.getMatrix().reset();
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.rotateX(0);
        mCamera.getMatrix(t.getMatrix());
        mCamera.restore();
        t.getMatrix().preTranslate(-dx, -dy);
        t.getMatrix().postTranslate(dx, dy);
    }

    if (getChildCount() == 1) {
        this.invalidate();
    } else {
        child.invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

During the initial implementation of this behaviour each fragment of the viewpager just contained a simple View with a randomly colored background. When the transition rotation was behaving as required I replaced the simple colored view with a webview (as was required for the app) and begun testing the transition just loading each fragment's webview with the google homepage. When I did this I started to see strange behaviour during the viewpager's transition where as the pages go through the rotation transition the webview's content seems to become split between the two pages that are transitioning on screen and the rest of each page's layout just displays the background of the webview (which I've set to blue).

Below is a screenshot of the transition in action with the initial implementation (using just the colored views):

[image]

As you can see the blue page is scrolling out to the top and the green page is scrolling in and both have the transition rotation applied to them. This is the correct, expected behaviour.

The next screenshot is taken from the app when I've replaced the colored views with webview loading the google homepage. As I mentioned, the webview in each page is not showing the full content of the view during transition and is instead displaying the blue color I have set for the background.

[image]

I've done a lot of searching on this site to try and find someone from the past having a similar issue but didn't find anything useful. I'd really appreciate some help here as I'm a bit baffled as to why this is happening and can't really spend anymore time on it. If someone out there has any idea why this behaviour is occurring with the webview specifically that would be useful as it may allow me to come up with a solution/workaround.

I tried a couple of workarounds. One where I tried to pause the webview during scroll and restart it after and another where during scrolling I replaced the webview with an imageview containing a snapshot of the webview when scrolling begun. Neither of these solutions seemed to work.

I've uploaded a video to youtube, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjkf1y2U4rI&feature=youtu.be), that shows the webview scrolling issue more clearly.

Any help/thoughts/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fear the problem is with the WebView that is not really good friend with canvas transformations.
You could try to take a snapshot of the webview and replace the WebView with snapshots during the scroll.